# Generic CollectionView in swift

Tags: swift, generic-collections

I try to generics collectionview as tableview like this but it's not succeed. Please give me a suggest if you can. Thank in advanced

```
class BaseTableVC<T: BaseCell<U>, U>: UITableViewController {

let cellId = "cellId"
var items = [U]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(T.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,   numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt  indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! BaseCell<U>
    cell.item = self.items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
}

class BaseCell<U> : UITableViewCell {
var item: U!

}
```

struct and cell for struct 
    struct Dog{
       let name: String
    }

```
class DogCell: BaseCell<Dog> {
override var item: Dog!{
    didSet{
        textLabel?.text = item.name

    }
}
}
```

in viewcontroller,

```
class SomeListController: BaseTableVC<DogCell, Dog> {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    items = [Dog(name: "Cho 1"), Dog(name: "Cho 2")]
   }
}
```

Comment: Where and what is the issue? What is `Dog`?

Comment: just example. struct Dog{
    let name: String
}

Comment: Ok so what is the issue?

Comment: oh, I tried do this with collectionview, but it's not succeed. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you share that code you tried? The above code looks fine so its not possible to guess the solution without the actual erroneous code.